# How can I download (at once) all the video files I uploaded to BlueJeans?

Tags: bulk-download, bluejeans

How can I bulk download all the video files I uploaded to [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/)?

I don't want to have to download the videos  manually one by one.

[image]